# VB.net fitting objects/shapes inside box

Tags: vb.net, graphics, polygon

I have some shapes (ellipses, triangles, squares, stars and other polygons), I want to find the (nearly) minimum size of area that I can fit them in. (I have the point(x,y) of the corners of shapes)

Comment: Well the minimum size of any of these shapes would be 1 px theorically.. I don't understand what you are trying to do. What are the goals? What is the context? Maybe show a drawing of what you want to make?

Comment: I'm trying to fit 10 triangles, 5 circles and 4 stars as an example and there should be at least 1 px between them, how big the plate should be that I'm going to fit those 2D objects?

Comment: You have a quite complicated program in view. If I were you I would start by fixing the geometries of every polygon. Then if you really want to program it fully, it would need to try multiple times with different patterns to find the minimum area the plate would be. This is quite complicated and need multiple algorithms to place them. I would suggest skipping doing the program (if unexperienced) and just making an estimate. You could estimate it close to what a plate filled with circles would take.

Comment: The perfect algorithm would be quite complicated. If you want to simplify it, you could easely convert all of your polygon to rectangle. Then just figure out how to position these rectangle. When you have the position of the rectangle, just substitue them with your polygon.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sifu I don't have chance to skip this program, I have to do it:D, the_lotus I liked your idea thank you, I'm going to try it.